# Facing error while accessing cassandra data through Solr in DSE

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

When I issue this query on solr(separate db) then it is working. But when I am accessing cassandra data through Solr query(I am using DSE) then it returns nothing. And it is giving some error related UserCacheField. So How to enable UserCacheField in a solr query?

Update
My Query is

```
select * FROM trackfleet_db.location WHERE 
  solr_query='{"facet":{"pivot":"date,latitude,longitude"},"q":":"}' ;
```

And I am getting following error

```
 InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
 message="Field cache is disabled, set the field=date to be docValues=true 
 and reindex. Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage,
 then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters."
```

Comment: Please share the error message & other information, like, query, version of DSE, etc.

Comment: My Query is -
select * FROM trackfleet_db.location WHERE solr_query='{"facet":{"pivot":"date,latitude,longitude"},"q":"*:*"}' ;


And I am getting following error 
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Field cache is disabled, set the field=date to be docValues=true and reindex.  Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage, then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters."

Comment: And I am using DSE 5.1

Answer (score 0):

The best approach should be enabling of `docValues` on given field (`date`) & reindex the data.

But it looks like that you have this field defined with `date` type, that ([per documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/aboutFields.html)) doesn't support docValues, so you may need to change type for this field to `timestamp` (I'm not sure that you can use copy field with different type).